# SQL combine 2 tables to one, update missing values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
users, user_profile, plus
```

I want to combine table **users** with **user_profile** and fill missing values to table **plus**. References are in image marked with color.

Unique key in `plus` table is `email` column.

Tables and references:

[image: tables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE plus AS p
JOIN users AS u ON p.email = u.email
JOIN user_profile AS up ON up.user_id = u.id
SET p.reg_date = u.reg_date, p.nickname = up.nickname, p.name = up.name,
    p.surname = up.surname, p.birthday = up.birthday, p.gender = up.gender
```